# How to update Google Spreadsheet cell using PHP API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I would like to know how I can interact with a Google spreadsheet using PHP.

I've looked through many pages of Google's documentation, however, none of that is doing what I'm looking for.

My goal is to be able to change the content of the cells using oAuth (not the email/pass).

Please, forgive me if this is a RTFM issues, but I did spend more than 2 weeks with this with no result. :/

Comment: Where have you been looking? There are lots of examples for this using the spreadsheet feed api. Its all there. First learn about oauth which you can practice in the oauth2 playground. Google both.

Comment: would you like to give me a working example please ? i do get the oAuth key and even success to get my spreadsheet data such as title and mimeType using this : 

**$file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();** hoever, i don't know who to edit a cell

Comment: Its all in the api docs. Or use zend for a php wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solutions i got for my issue :

[Zend GData Library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.html)

[Zend Gdata for Spreadsheet with the examples code](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html)

Comment: This is pretty outdated now.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with ***[asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client)*** library.

1. Install the library via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

   ```
   "require": {
       "asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client": "dev-master"
   }
   ```
2. Bootstrap composer in your PHP file:

   ```
   require('vendor/autoload.php');
   ```
3. Follow the steps to get a Google API client ID, client email, and P12 access key, as explained here:
   https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/wiki/How-to-use-%22Service-account%22-authorization-(rather-than-user-based-access-refresh-tokens)
4. Use the following code:

   ```php
   $accessToken = getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile(CLIENT_ID_HERE, CLIENT_EMAIL_HERE, P12_FILE_PATH_HERE);
   use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
   use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;
   ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance(new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken));

   // Load spreadsheet and worksheet
   $worksheet = (new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService())
       ->getSpreadsheets()
       ->getByTitle('xxxxxxxxx')       // Spreadsheet name
       ->getWorksheets()
       ->getByTitle('xxxxxxxxx');      // Worksheet name
   $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

   // Uncomment this to find out what Google calls your column names
   // print_r($listFeed->getEntries()[0]->getValues());

   // Add a new blank row to the spreadsheet, using the column headings
   $listFeed->insert(['name' => 'Simon', 'age' => 25, 'gender' => 'male']);

   /**
    * Retrieves a Google API access token by using a P12 key file,
    * client ID and email address
    *
    * These three things may be obtained from 
    * https://console.developers.google.com/
    * by creating a new "Service account"
    */
   function getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile($clientId, $clientEmail, $pathToP12File) {
       $client = new Google_Client();
       $client->setClientId($clientId);

       $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
           $clientEmail,
           array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
           file_get_contents($pathToP12File)
       );

       $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

       if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
           $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
       }

       $service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
       return $service_token->access_token;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, how can I insert rows using "Web Application" rather than "Service Account"?

Comment: Hi @Subhra, you need to follow the instructions at https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client and use the OAuth workflow.  The developer has also posted some OAuth examples here: https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-oauth

Comment: Hi @Simon, Thanks. Was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Drive API doesn't provide any means to edit a spreadsheet, [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) contains low level cell modification methods. As a note, you can't use Google APIs PHP Client Library to consume the Spreadsheets API.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i just find a solutions with Zend GData, it's the ONLY way for now, as Google provide official support for the new APIS only for .NET, Java and Python !

Answer (score 2):

API v4, you can use curl. Get Access Token then use curl. You can update single row or multiple rows Or you can update single column or multiple columns. If you are updating Single Column or Single row then use https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheetID/values/RowORColumnRange/?valueInputOption=RAW&includeValuesInResponse=true

```
sheetID = FileID
RowORColumnRange = Sheet!A1 or Sheet!B2
```

Pass value data with PUT method like

```
$update['values'] = [[1234]];
```

for the Batch Update instead of use method values in the URL you can change to values:batchUpdate. and then pass other data in array and use method POST;

You can ref this https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration